# int arrays in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays

i wonder about int array in c affect to memory.
for example we opened char array `char array[10];`
it wont open 10 it'll open 11 because of `'\0'`
is there same situation on int array?
when we declare `int abc[10];` will it open array that is 10 int size or 11 like char?
Thanks...

Comment: What do you think `char array[10]` is?

Comment: i meant declarating array for example we declaret char x[10]; it seems x[10]='c'; illegal after i read messages.Am i rignt?

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong with regards to `char array[10]`. This will *not* declare an array of 11 elements, only 10, *including* the terminating `'\0'`. This means that if you put a string of ten characters in the array, it will overflow.

`some_type name[10]` will *always* declare an array of 10 elements, never more, never less.

Comment: If you put *a string of* ten characters in the array, it overflows.

Answer (score 2):

Any array declaration will have x number of elements

> type array[x]

not x+1.

not even the char one.

read here more about arrays:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Answer (score 1):

I think declaring char array[10] allocates exactly 10 bytes of space, it is your job to manage memory with '\0' if you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

`int abc[10]` creates an array of 10 ints, with subscripts 0 through 9. Changing the type (e.g., to `char abc[10]` doesn't change the number of items in the array.

With an array of char, the NUL terminator is considered part of the string, so if you provide an initializer and specify a size, the size must be at least as large as the size of the string including the NUL terminator. If you don't specify the size, the size will be the length of the string including the NUL terminator.

```
char a[] = "A string"; // sizeof(a)==9
```

Note, however, that C is slightly different in this respect -- in C you can specify an initializer and a size that does *not* include space for the NUL terminator, and it'll still compile.

```
char a[9] = "A string"; // allowed in either C or C++
char a[8] = "A string"; // allowed in C, but not C++.
```

Comment: i ve always used char a[8] = "A string"; like that since i started C. that way where is newline a[8] is'\0' right?

Comment: @user1030629: no -- with `char a[8]`, the valid subscripts go from a[0] through a[7]. You can't depend on a[8] containing any particular  value. In a typical case, it'll refer to whatever byte happens to follow (the valid parts of) `a` in memory. That might happen to be a '\0', but might just as well be something else.

Comment: i see thanks but im still confused i used always char a[8] = "A string"; and it never crahed or couldnt find null terminator on puts printf etc...

Comment: @user1030629: Pure luck -- though whether it was good luck or bad is open to question. Generally if you're initializing the string, I'd advise just `char a[] = "A string";`, and letting the compiler do the counting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "opened" an array.  If you declare:

```
char array[10];
```

you define an array of ten `char`.  If you declare:

```
int array[10];
```

you define an array of ten `int`.  Both uninitialized unless defined
with static lifetime.

The appended `'\0'` only affects string literals and initialization
strings.

Answer (score 0):

> for example we opened char array char array[10]; it wont open 10 it ll open 11 because of '\0'

Wrong. In C, you are expected to take care of your terminating `\0`'s in strings - the compiler won't do any favour for you. If you declare a `char[10]`, you get exactly 10 `char`s, and the same is true for `int`s and all other types.

Answer (score 0):

A char array[10] *will* create an array of 10 elements. I think you are a bit confused because in c typically you have to create an array of size 11 to store a word of size 10, because you need to have one extra element for the '\0' char in the end. But still you have to declare the array to be of size 11, not 10. The compiler will not do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are somewhat confused about initializing an array of `char` in C++.  `char array[10]` will have size 10, not size 11, however, `char array[]  = "1234567890";` will have size 11 because the initialization knows that your char array needs to end with a newline character.